# Time format of Kubuntu 14.04 is in Khmer

Tags: kubuntu, time

I've just install Kubuntu 14.04 on my MacBook pro mid 2010. But the problem is even though i set the language in Local (system settings), the time format is still wrong.

It also effects Skype timeformat.

I need help.
Thank you.

Some images from my Computer.

Comment: Here are several image from my Laptop: http://i.imgur.com/LQtCBzP.png & http://i.imgur.com/3rizxcj.png